# Filtering the data in the dataframe according to the desired time in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, filter

I am new to python and pandas dataframe. Here is my creation code of my dataframe.

```
data = pd.read_csv('trafikdensity.csv',parse_dates=True,index_col=0)
```

What you see below is first 5 rows of my dataframe.
[image: Result of the first method]

I'd like to filter data between '07:00:00' and '21:00:00' for all days in January. This dataframe includes all days of January. First, I converted to datetime object and I tried to filter.

```
data['DATE_TIME'] = pd.to_datetime((data['DATE_TIME']))
data[data['DATE_TIME'].dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S').between('07:00:00','21:00:00')]
```

It gives me an empty data. Then, I tried to another method. It gives me also an empty data.

```
start_date01 = '2020-01-01 07:00:00'
end_date01 = '2020-01-01 21:00:00'
start_date02 = '2020-01-02 07:00:00'
end_date02 = '2020-01-02 21:00:00'
start_date03 = '2020-01-03 07:00:00'
end_date03 = '2020-01-03 21:00:00'

#greater than the start date and smaller than the end date
m1 = (data['DATE_TIME'] > start_date01) & (data['DATE_TIME'] <= end_date01) 
m2 = (data['DATE_TIME'] > start_date02) & (data['DATE_TIME'] <= end_date02) 
m3 = (data['DATE_TIME'] > start_date03) & (data['DATE_TIME'] <= end_date03)

data = data[np.logical_and.reduce([m1, m2, m3])]
```

[image: Result of the second method]

What am I missing? Or can I solve my problem with a different method? I took advantage of the solutions in Stackoverflow while doing these. But none of them have had a solution.

Comment: Please post your DataFrame creation code(in text form), so that we could test our solutions, thank you.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 I posted it. Thank you for feedback.

Comment: `data = data[data['DATE_TIME'].dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S').between('07:00:00','21:00:00')]` You could try to reassign to the dataframe.

Comment: @KabilanMohanraj I tried it but no changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data['DATE_TIME'] = pd.to_datetime(data['DATE_TIME'], yearfirst=True)
```

The **yearfirst** parameter has to be set to true.